# Why are assertions being logged in sentry when DEBUG = True?

Tags: django, sentry, raven

I'm in the middle of deploying sentry to handle our django error messages. I've configured django's `LOGGING` settings to only log when `DEBUG = False` via the use of `'filters': ['require_debug_false']`.

If I manually log an error in a django view as in the following example, it is successfully filtered and therefore not sent to sentry:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def view_name(request):
    logger.error('An error message')
    ...
```

However, if I use an `assert` statement as in the following example, it is **not** filtered and does get sent to sentry:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def view_name(request):
    assert False, 'An error message'
    ...
```

It is also worth noting that the `assert` statement does not get sent to the `mail_admins` handler, which also uses the same filter.

Can someone please help me prevent `assert` errors from begin sent to sentry whilst `DEBUG = True`?

Here are the package versions I am using:

```
Django==1.6.7
raven==5.1.1
```

And here are the relevant parts of my settings.py:

```
DEBUG = True
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'include_html': True,
        },
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins', 'sentry'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In raven-python 3.0.0 [`DEBUG` setting in Django no longer disables Raven](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/blob/94a6d6a87383b37abfd9fb459e19d2f5eec65c3e/CHANGES#L146).
[From documentation](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integrations/django.html#setup):

> Raven to install a hook in Django that will automatically report
>   uncaught exceptions

In your case, `assert` generate `uncaught exceptions` **AssertionError**, which logged in Sentry.

To disable this functionality  set `dsn = None` or remove dsn ([source](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/issues/538#issuecomment-66835959)):

```
 RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'dsn': None
 }
```